# How to specify second argument in Jest v24.6 toMatchSnapshot(propertyMatchers?, hint?)?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm updating Jest snapshot tests after upgrading from Jest v22 to Jest v24. The toMatchSnapshot() function changed to taking 2 parameters instead of 1, as seen here -

v22 - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/22.x/expect#tomatchsnapshotoptionalstring

v24 - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchsnapshotpropertymatchers-hint

I still want to use the hint (string) parameter but I don't want to use the propertyMatchers (object) parameter. Unfortunately, if I just pass in an empty object literal (ex. toMatchSnapshot({}, 'test')), it causes the generated snapshot output to be an object of ~100000+ lines rather than the XML output as before.

Any ideas on how I might be able to do this? Has anyone run into a similar problem with generated snapshot output?

A sample implementation would look like this:

```
test('Test', () => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        expect(file.data).toMatchSnapshot({}, file.path);
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a string in as the first argument instead of an object, Jest will treat it as the hint ('optional snapshot name' in v22 terminology):

```
test('Test', () => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        expect(file.data).toMatchSnapshot(file.path);
    });
)};
```

Comment: Interesting! When I tried it, it was making *file.path* the expected output. Looks like the argument I was passing in (file.path) wasn't a string. Passing it in with .join() (ie. file.path.join()) works as I wanted it to.

Thanks for your help!